# php explode string with Uppercase if lowercase letter exists before it without space

Tags: php, split, explode

```
$str="Hello MotoBell RingsKing Speech";
```

I need explode this string by uppercase letter if lowercase letter exists before it.

like this:

```
$splitted=array(
      0=>"Hello Moto",
      1=>"Bell Rings",
      2=>"King Speech"
     );
```

any ideas?

I try use that reg_ex, but not working:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-ZА-Я])/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: Use the regular expressions, Luke!

Comment: Can you give any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var_dump(preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', 'Hello MotoBell RingsKing Speech'))

// array(3) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(10) "Hello Moto"
//   [1]=>
//   string(10) "Bell Rings"
//   [2]=>
//   string(11) "King Speech"
// }
```

Comment: In case you wonder about pattern, read any manual for lookahead/lookbehind regular expressions.